# Limits of functions and change of limits

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, proof-verification

Given $\textbf{a}$ , $\textbf{h}$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}^n$ and a function from some subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$

if $\lim_{\textbf{h} \rightarrow \textbf{0}}$ $f(\textbf{a+h})$ $=$ $\textbf{0}$ and $\textbf{h}=t \textbf{v}$ where t is just a real number.Then

$lim_{t \rightarrow 0}$ f($\textbf{a}$+t$\textbf{v}$) $=$ $0$

How can I turn this into a formal proof?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This need not be true if $v=0$. Assume $v \neq 0$ and let $\epsilon >0$. Choose $\delta >0$ such that $|f(a+h)| <\epsilon$ whenever $|h| <\delta$. Then $|f(a+tv)| <\epsilon$ whenever $|tv| <\delta$ which is true whenever $|h| <\frac {\delta} {|v|}$. (I am writing $|x|$ for the usual norm).

Answer (score 2):

If $t\to 0$ then $tv\to 0$

To do this formaly try and rewrite the increment parameter h as a function $h(t)$
of the real parameter $t$(which you basicly already did by setting $h=tv$)

The function $h(t)$ is then continious in each $t\in R$,meaning that
for arbitary real $t_{0}$ the limit of h at $t_{0}$ exists and equals the function
value at $t_{0}$

In particular for $t_{0}=0$
$$\lim_{t\to 0}h(t)=h(0)\ \text{and we know }\ h(0)=0$$

Then proceed
$$0=\lim_{h\to 0}f(a+h)=\lim_{t\to 0}f(a+h(t))=\lim_{t\to 0}f(a+tv)$$